# Make image smaller inside UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have an UIImageView that shows and image of a creditCard, My problem is that I want to make boarders around it, so the credit card wont touch the edges of the UIimageView, I dont want to change the UIImageView position on the screen so what can I do ?

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80tQb.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhCAt.png)

( unlike the example of the blue card it dosnt have to leave spaces only from the sides, it could shrink it from all sides )

Answer (score 0):

You basically have (3) three options that can fix this.

1. Adjust the `UIViewContentMode` **contentMode** of the `UIImageView` so that it appropriately displays the image (this will only work however if the image you are using scales to fit without touching the border.
2. Use a `UIButton` instead and simply adjust the image insets until your satisfied (just disable the button or set user interaction to no here to "mimic" an image view)
3. Create a wrapper method that creates a *new* image to your desired size. Something like this should work just fine

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(< some width > , < some height >);
```

Then just create a new image capture with the size you've chosen

```
CGFloat scale = MAX(size.width/image.size.width, size.height/image.size.height);
CGFloat width = image.size.width * scale;
CGFloat height = image.size.height * scale;
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake((size.width - width)/2.0f,
                              (size.height - height)/2.0f,
                              width,
                              height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
[image drawInRect:imageRect];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

---

From here you should then be able to just apply a border width and color to get your desired result!

---

I *guess* a fourth (4th) option could be manually shrinking the image (with some photo editor) so that it renders (fits) into your image view with the appropriate padding around the image. I think the others are easier and best practice though.